# Как установить курсор при открытии программы в поле без клика на это поле мышкой?

Tags: xml, windows-7

Друг сделал программу, попросили при её открытии сделать так чтобы курсор автоматически устанавливался в поле. Как это сделать?

Comment: на каком языке написана программа? уточняйте вопрос

Comment: на языке xml

Comment: не поможете?